# ReferenceError: getBanificiarydata is not defined

Tags: javascript

When i click to open fancybox i face this error.

```
ReferenceError: getBanificiarydata is not defined
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'scrolling': 'no',
        'titleShow': 'false',
        'autoDimensions': 'false',
        'padding': 0,
        'centerOnScroll': false,
        'onComplete': function() {
            $("#fancybox-wrap").css({
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'top': '50px'
            });
        },
        'onStart': function() {
            $("#fancybox-overlay").css({
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'top': '0px',
                'left': '0px'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<td><a class="various" href="#inline" onclick="getBanificiarydata('<?php echo $benefeciary->benID?>','edit');">Edit</a></td>
```

it opens the fancybox but just close button and black putty

Answer (score 0):

Well, it means that the global function `getBanificiarydata` is not defined. You need to define this function and ensure it's globally available (if it's defined withing another function, assign it to the `window` object).

Possibly you also get the errors because of the wrong spelling assuming the actual function is spelled properly...

Comment: <td><a class="various" href="#inline" onclick="getBanificiarydata('<?php echo $benefeciary->benID?>','edit');">Edit</a></td>

Comment: on click i called this function

Comment: Yes, I think everyone reading your question realizes that. But where/how do you define that functon?!

Comment: which doesn't exist in global scope.